# Ms Bot V4(LUIS) Internal server error when I try to enable the channel Cortana

Tags: botframework, bots, cortana, cortana-skills-kit

When I try to enable Cortana in my Nodejs Bot, I get the message error internal server error, probably there something wrong in my code despite it works fine locally and in Ms Teams.
Is there a way to obtain a more specific error?
Analyzing the browser dev toolbar I get a 400 for the following http POST:

https://dev.botframework.com/api/bots//channels/cortana/deployment/ring

Answer (score 2):

Did you check:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cortana/skills/known-issues#luisdialog-fails-on-skill-launch
- https://github.com/Microsoft/cortana-skills-samples/blob/master/Consumer/Node/V4Patches/12.nlp-with-luis.diff

I would venture a guess that you do not handle the empty message / welcome intent on first turn.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but this doesn't solve my issue, btw is something in my code because if I create a new Bot v4 Nodejs I can activate Cortana

Comment: https://blog.botframework.com/2017/10/19/debug-channel-locally-using-ngrok/ Set a breakbpoint on onTurn or your first activity handler and step through until you find what blows up in a source level debugger.

Comment: After code refactoring the error is changed in "Incorrect image type. Image types supported: "Unsupported URI scheme. Must be data, http or https" do you know where this come from?

Comment: Thanks for your reply I solved the issue uploading a new skill icon picture

Comment: Can you clarify the conditions?  Sounds like a bug. You should not be able to publish a cortana channel without an image.  In self host, you should have a placeholder if you do not upload an image.

Comment: There was already an image in the skill icon that I uploaded three months ago, after that I uploaded a new one I was able to activate Cortana

Answer (score 0):

Finally I activated Cortana Channel by uploading again the skill icon